# how to call GraphQl API of Specific Store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, graphql

I want to get the data of specific store using API in **REST APIs** we can do this by giving store code before APIs endpoint but how can we do that in **GraphQl APIs**

In Rest APIs : /rest/**StoreCode**/V1/integration/customer/token

what to do in GraphQl APis

Answer (score 1):

You can send this "storeCode" in **Headers** rather than being included in url as in REST. So to add localization to your API GraphQl you could send key:value, like this: store:en Or store:fr [image]

Answer (score 0):

> **GraphQL request accepts the Store into headers.**

```
Header Key : Store

Header Value : <store_view_code>
```

**The store view code on which to perform the request. The value can be default or the code that is defined when a store view is created.**

[image]

*I recommend you to use [Altair GraphQL Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/altair-graphql-client/flnheeellpciglgpaodhkhmapeljopja?hl=en)*

[For More Header click Here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/headers/#request-headers)

***I Hope This Helps You.***